# EXSLT and xsltproc getting an error

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

I have an XSL file which works like a charm, at least, until I wanted to use regular expressions from EXSLT, what I did:
added :

```
  xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
  extension-element-prefixes="regexp"
```

and used this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="regexp:test(
                       Location/Politic/@Country,
                       'Espa.a',
                       'i'
                    )"
             >ES</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

somewhere in my XSL. this lead to the following error:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function test not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 3 objects left on the stack.
```

any idea what am I doing wrong in here, I strictly followed the instructions over

> http://www.exslt.org/

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like your processor doesn't support that extension (or part of that extension).

Comment: The output from `xsltproc --dumpextensions` does not include regexp (using libxml 20706, libxslt 10126, libexslt 815).

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: xsltproc (the linux shell command)

Comment: Btw, I've also tried: saxonb-xslt, which gives me this error:   Cannot find a matching 3-argument function named {http://exslt.org/regular-expressions}test()
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were report

Answer (score 1):

If you need EXSLT regexp functions, you have to use 4Suite written in python.
Saxon doesn't know this extension, but it is XSLT 2.0 processor, so you can use fn:matches instead of regexp:test. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/ .

Another way is to define your own extension function.

In Saxon:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xsl:function name="regexp:test" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="regexp" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="fn:matches($regexp, $str)"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In Xalan:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    extension-element-prefixes="func java regexp"
>

    <func:function name="regexp:test">
        <xsl:param name="regexp"/>
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:variable name="testResult" select="java:matches($regexp, $str)"/>
        <func:result select="$testResult"/>
    </func:function>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html